# Ruby_noexec_wraper: no such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I ran into this problem today, haven't been having an issue. Any suggestions where to look to correct this issue.

I noticed having the issue when running any commands with rake on any of my apps.

I am running Mac OSX Lion with Ruby 1.9.3

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved my own issue.

I uninstalled rake and than ran bundle install. Fixed my issue.